# Html element set autofocus dynamically in React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, kendo-react-ui

I have two sibling component.

one component contains textbox,checkbox,dropdown controls in it.

another component contains Kendo Grid.

whenever user clicks on grid row i want to set focus on one of the element in above 
component which include textbox.

Approach used:

1.I don't want to use ref as i have multiple controls in one component.

2.I have dynamically added autofocus attribute to input element.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to SO! I believe `refs` is the most easy way to achieve this. When you have multiple controls, you can create an array/object/map of `refs` and refer them later

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** I am **not** sure if these solutions are best practices in React

There are 2 approaches for this, both using `refs`, but with smarter implementations:

- Create a wrapper around the inputs and assign `refs` to it. Whenever you want to focus on an input, simply use `wrapperRef.querySelector('[name=yourInput])`. Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/195kkrpvq
- Create an object which stores the name of the fields as keys and their refs as values. Simply use `this.yourRefsObject[yourInputName].focus()` to focus on an input. Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/61jl7q9v43

Again, I am not certain whether these implementations are best practices, but they should do the job for now